# RedShift self-join on array

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table within Redshift with a self-referential `ParentID` to join back to the `ProductID` to create a hierarchy.

Basic structure (full table is c6k records, with arrays up to 90 IDs):

```
CREATE TABLE sandbox.productmk2 (
    productid integer ENCODE az64,
    product character varying(500) ENCODE lzo,
    parentid super
)
DISTSTYLE AUTO;
```

| ProductID | Product | ParentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Headwear | `[0]` |
| 2 | Woolwear | `[0]` |
| 3 | Hats | `[1,2]` |

`ParentID` is stored as a SUPER type and contains an array.

From a bit of research online, it has been suggested to use the ANY condition. However, I get the following error,  even if I cast it again as an array.

> *ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side*,

```
    SELECT a.ProductID, a.product, b.product as Parent
    FROM sandbox.productmk2 A
    JOIN sandbox.productmk2 b on b.productid = ANY(a.parentid)
```

Expected output

| ProductID | Product | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Hats | Headwear |
| 3 | Hats | Woolwear |

Changing the `ANY(a.parentid)` to `a.parentid[0]` successfully joins on the first ID, so the array looks to be stored correctly.

Is there something I'm missing regarding the `ALL` operator, or is there a better way to deal with this?

Unfortunately, it's challenging to research, considering this is a relatively new feature in Redshift, and most articles I come across say arrays aren't supported in RS...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share table definition ?

Comment: @SelVazi, I've updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way around to get a working solution, although it is far from elegant (I'm not a fan of joining in the where clause).

If anybody can improve on this, I'll be very keen to learn!

```
SELECT A.*, C.PRODUCT AS Parent
FROM sandbox.productmk2 AS A , a.parentid AS b, sandbox.productmk2 AS C
WHERE B = C.productid;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're dealing with array handling in Redshift. Instead of using the ANY condition, try using UNNEST to expand the arrays and then join on the elements

```
SELECT a.ProductID, a.product, b.product as Parent
FROM sandbox.productmk2 a
JOIN sandbox.productmk2 b ON b.productid = 
UNNEST(a.parentid)
```

Comment: Thanks Lenroy, however I'm getting the following error when trying that method
ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNNEST" Position: 125